# Como carregar background com efeito fade em css?

Tags: javascript, css

Bem, tenho uma página html com uma imagem de fundo, só que quando a página carrega, ela aparece de uma forma esquisita. Tem como ela carregar suavemente na página?
Estou usando um código que altera a imagem a cada reload da página.

```
<script> 
var fundos = 20; 
ran = Math.round(Math.random() * (fundos-1))+1 
if (ran == (1)) { 
url_background=("img/1.png"); 
} 
if (ran == (2)) { 
url_background=("img/2.png") 
} 
if (ran == (3)) { 
url_background=("img/3.png"); 
} 
if (ran == (4)) { 
url_background=("img/4.png") 
} 
if (ran == (5)) { 
url_background=("img/5.png"); 
} 
if (ran == (6)) { 
url_background=("img/6.png") 
} 
if (ran == (7)) { 
url_background=("img/7.png"); 
} 
if (ran == (8)) { 
url_background=("img/8.png") 
}
if (ran == (9)) { 
url_background=("img/9.png"); 
} 
if (ran == (10)) { 
url_background=("img/10.png"); 
} 
if (ran == (11)) { 
url_background=("img/11.png") 
}
if (ran == (12)) { 
url_background=("img/12.png"); 
} 
if (ran == (13)) { 
url_background=("img/13.png") 
}
if (ran == (14)) { 
url_background=("img/14.png") 
}
if (ran == (15)) { 
url_background=("img/15.png"); 
} 
if (ran == (16)) { 
url_background=("img/16.png") 
}
if (ran == (17)) { 
url_background=("img/17.png"); 
} 
if (ran == (18)) { 
url_background=("img/18.png") 
}
if (ran == (19)) { 
url_background=("img/19.png"); 
} 
if (ran == (20)) { 
url_background=("img/20.png") 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Para carregar a imagem e só mostrar quando já estiver em memória:**

```
var fundos = 20;
var ran = Math.round(Math.random() * (fundos - 1)) + 1
var url_background = "img/" + ran + ".png";

function carrega() {
    $('<img/>').attr('src', 'http://picture.de/image.png').load(function () {
        $(this).remove(); // para libertar memória e evitar fugas de memória
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + url_background + ')');
    });
    $('.main').fadeIn('slow');
}
```

A ideia é: crie um novo elemento que nunca vai usar mas com o endereço da imagem que quer. Usando o `.load()` pode saber quando a imagem está carregada e aí pode aplicar essa imagem ao `body` pois ela já está carregada na memória.

<sub>[fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5058336/2256325)</sub>

**Para fazer um fade in na imagem pode fazer com CSS:**

```
body {
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Dessa maneira quando o jQuery aplicar `$('body').css('background-image', 'url(http://picture.de/image.png)');` a imagem de fundo vai fazer uma transição de `0.2` segundos.

Comment: Vou tentar.....

Comment: Não funcionou, tirei o código que muda o background com o reload, mas não deu certo.

Comment: @GustavoBarbosa tem o jQuery carregado?

Comment: Desculpe a demora. Sim. <script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode definir o background em um elemento fora do conteúdo, exemplo:

```
<div class="meuBackground"><section><p>Seu conteudo aqui</p></section></div>
```

Definir as camadas na css:

```
div {
    z-index:0;
}

section { 
    z-index:1; 
}
```

E com javascript controlar o background e o aparecimento com opacity:

```
div {
  opactity:0;
}
```